# What does it mean to return an iterator? Java

Tags: java, iterator

I have to write a class that implements the Iterable interface. I'm confused about what it means to return an iterator object. An iterator just goes through the elements of a list, so how would I return this as an object? Would I return a list that was able to be iterated through or what? How can an iterator be an object when all it does is go through or change data in other objects?

Comment: Show what you tried !

Comment: An iterator object implements the Iterator interface - see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: I didn't try anything, I'm confused about the concept in general, mostly about considering an iterator an object when it seems more like just a couple methods? Also, I would ask but I won't be able to see him for about a week.

Comment: Write a class that has "hasNext", "Next", "remove" etc functions

Comment: An example may be more helpful than an explanation. [Here's the source code for the iterator for `ArrayList`.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr)

Comment: Returning an `Iterator` doesn't mean you would "return a list", but the object that you return, which would implement `Iterator`, would most likely have private variables that **refer** to the list, or refer to an element of the list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of a very simplistic list. It represents the list as linked elements.
The iterator object is created as an anonymous inner class holding the current element as the state. Each call of `iterator()` creates a new iterator object.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SimplisticList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  /*
   * A list element encapsulates a data value and a reference to the next
   * element.
   */
  private static class Element<T> {
    private T data;
    private Element<T> next;

    Element(T data) {
      this.data = data;
      next = null;
    }

    public T getData() {
      return data;
    }

    public Element<T> getNext() {
      return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Element<T> next) {
      this.next = next;
    }

  }

  // We only need a reference to the head of the list.
  private Element<T> first = null;

  // The list is empty if there is no first element.
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
  }

  // Adding a new list element.
  // For an empty list we only have to set the head.
  // Otherwise we have to find the last element to add the new element.
  public void add(T data) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
      first = new Element<T>(data);
    } else {
      Element<T> current = first;
      while(current.getNext() != null) {
        current = current.getNext();
      }
      current.setNext(new Element<T>(data));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    // Create an anonymous implementation of Iterator<T>.
    // We need to store the current list element and initialize it with the
    // head of the list.
    // We don't implement the remove() method here. 
    return new Iterator<T>() {
      private Element<T> current = first;

      @Override
      public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
      }

      @Override
      public T next() {
        T result = null;
        if(current != null) {
          result = current.getData();
          current = current.getNext();
        }
        return result;
      }

      @Override
      public void remove() {
        // To be done ...
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: This is the true solution.

Answer (score 2):

Returing an iterator means returning an instance of a class that implements the Iterator interface. This class has to implement `hasNext()`,`next()` and `remove()`. The constructor of the class should initialize the instance in a way that `next()` would return the first element of the data structure you are iterating over (if it's not empty).

Comment: So I it would just be a list that implements those three methods? Why would I not just implement iterator instead of iterable then? Would I have to implement both iterator and iterable?

Comment: An `Iterator` can only be used once.  An `Iterable` can generate multiple `Iterator`s.  You generally have to implement both.

Comment: Note that `hasNext()`, `next()`, and `remove()` only allow you to move _forward_ through whatever you're iterating over.

Comment: @trosy An `Iterable` is the thing that you're traversing, such as a `List`. An `Iterator` is the object holding information about the state of the traversal, such as the current position in the list. Multiple iterators could be running on the same list simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of an iterator that goes through an `String[]` array:

```
public class MyIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    private String[] arr;
    private int index;

    public MyIterator(String[] arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.index = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < arr.length;
    }

    public String next() {
        return arr[index++];
    }

}
```

(You also need `remove()` but that would just throw an exception.)  Note that when you construct one of these iterators with `new MyIterator(myStringArray)`, you construct an object that has a **reference** to the array.  The `Iterator` wouldn't *be* the array itself, or any part of it, but it has a private variable that refers to it.  An `Iterator` for a list or for any other data structure (or even for things that aren't data structures) would follow a similar pattern.