# How to return an arraylist iterator? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new in java programming. I have searched several posts that related to iterator but still cannot figure out how to do it.

I have 2 classes. **Order** and **OrderItem**.
I need to implement the interface `Iterable<OrderItem>` to being able to iterate through the items using the for-each loop.

```
public class OrderItem {
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;

    public OrderItem(Product initialProduct, int initialQuantity)
    {
        this.product = initialProduct;
        this.quantity = initialQuantity;
    }
    public Product getProduct()
    {
        return this.product;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return this.quantity;
    }
```

This is the class Order

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Order implements Iterable<OrderItem> {

private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    public Order()
    {
    }

    public void addItem(OrderItem orderitem)
    {
        items.add(orderitem);
    }

    public Iterator<OrderItem> iterator()
    {
        return this.iterator(); //How to do this part??
    }

    public int getNumberOfItems()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
    }
```

Here [What does it mean to return an iterator? Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566641/what-does-it-mean-to-return-an-iterator-java) suggests doing it like what i learn about linked list.
But i am using ArrayList now. I don't need to do like this? Or do I?

Comment: What's wrong with returning ```items.iterator()```?

Comment: Stackoverflow error

Comment: Oops... I made a stupid mistake. It seems fine when i changed items.iterator(). Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the `iterator` from the List of **OrdemItem** here:

```
private List<OrderItem> items = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
```

and do:

```
public Iterator<OrderItem> iterator()
{
    return items.iterator();  
}
```

instead of doing

```
public Iterator<OrderItem> iterator()
{
    return this.iterator(); //How to do this part??
}
```