# java returning iterator of generic list of generic specific object

Tags: java, generics, iterator

In a java method, I must return the following:

```
 Iterator<List<Person>>
```

I wrote the method that creates a new list, adds the Persons to it:

```
LinkedList<Person> list = new LinkedList<Person>();
...
list.add(new Person(...))
...
```

But when I need to return the iterator as I was obligated in method signature, I'm confused.

returning:

```
return list.iterator();
```

causes compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterator<Person> to Iterator<List<Person>>
```

What should I change in my method in order to follow the method signature?

Thanks

Comment: You should return Iterator<Person> I'm not sure why you are iterating List<Person> if your linked list is just Person.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566641/what-does-it-mean-to-return-an-iterator-java

Comment: Who said you want an `Iterator<List<Person>>`?  That just makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

This method can not help it but do not think so.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Exam2 {

    public static Iterator<List<Person>> getIterator(){
        LinkedList<Person> list = new LinkedList<Person>();
        list.add(new Person());

        LinkedList<List<Person>> Parentlist = new LinkedList<List<Person>>();
        Parentlist.add(list);

        return Parentlist.iterator();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( getIterator() );
    }
}

class Person{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter for an `Iterator` is the type it will return, not the type of the collection over which the iterator will be used.

In your case, return `Iterator<Person>`